# Error 1264, do I need DECIMAL, FLOAT or DOUBLE

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is when I try to insert any decimal number to my table, it throws an error that is the following. ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'price' at row 1. I am using decimal. It is necessary to change it to a FLOAT or DOUBLE.

```
INSERT INTO items (name_items, price) VALUES ('Red', 35.00), ('Racket', 65.00), ('Paq-3', 4.75), ('Paq-6', 5.00), ('bag', 10.00);
```

I don't expect the error output.

Comment: Please include the table definition for `items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the definition for your decimal `price` column, but here is a definition which should resolve the error:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    name_items VARCHAR(255),
    price DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```

The type `DECIMAL(10,2)` means 10 *total* units of precision, 2 of which are to the *right* of the decimal place, to cover your level of precision in the insert statement.

Comment: Yes your answer resolve my problem, thank you very much